# Subquery performance on simple case

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql 10 - Ubuntu LTS latest  - 1CPU 2GB Ram - No other sw installed
Two tables, both whith their indexes:
follows (22 records)
tips (2.5 M records)

```
select users_id_to from follows where users_id_from =1
```

takes 0,041 msec

```
select tips.id
from tips
where tips.users_id in (2,3,4,5,6,8,79407,38463,42798,94150,76554,56777,71407,51788,4624,41079,13549,75920,18979,6078,26178,18316) 

Bitmap Heap Scan on tips  (cost=101.72..2122.76 rows=556 width=8) (actual time=0.267..1.120 rows=597 loops=1)   
  Recheck Cond: (users_id = ANY ('{2,3,4,5,6,8,79407,38463,42798,94150,76554,56777,71407,51788,4624,41079,13549,75920,18979,6078,26178,18316}'::bigint[]))  
  Heap Blocks: exact=594    
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tips_idx_users_id01  (cost=0.00..101.58 rows=556 width=0) (actual time=0.188..0.188 rows=597 loops=1)    
        Index Cond: (users_id = ANY ('{2,3,4,5,6,8,79407,38463,42798,94150,76554,56777,71407,51788,4624,41079,13549,75920,18979,6078,26178,18316}'::bigint[]))  
Planning time: 0.210 ms 
Execution time: 1.193 ms
```

takes 1.2 msec (was 4,7 msec at the first run)

```
select tips.id
from tips
where tips.users_id in (select users_id_to
                        from follows
                        where users_id_from = 1
                       )


Merge Semi Join  (cost=2.29..22.07 rows=573 width=8) (actual time=0.540..10632.242 rows=597 loops=1)    
  Merge Cond: (tips.users_id = follows.users_id_to) 
  Buffers: shared hit=1095506 read=1264002  
  ->  Index Scan using tips_idx_users_id01 on tips  (cost=0.43..205139.43 rows=2500000 width=16) (actual time=0.021..10180.667 rows=2353909 loops=1)    
        Buffers: shared hit=1095505 read=1264002    
  ->  Sort  (cost=1.77..1.82 rows=22 width=8) (actual time=0.051..0.084 rows=22 loops=1)    
        Sort Key: follows.users_id_to   
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB    
        Buffers: shared hit=1   
        ->  Seq Scan on follows  (cost=0.00..1.27 rows=22 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.019 rows=22 loops=1)   
              Filter: (users_id_from = 1)   
              Buffers: shared hit=1 
Planning time: 0.954 ms 
Execution time: 10632.376 ms
```

takes 10433 msec
Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE public.follows (
  id             bigserial NOT NULL,
  users_id_from  bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  users_id_to    bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  has_accepted   boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  created_on     timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT followings_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.tips (
  id             bigserial NOT NULL,
  users_id       bigint NOT NULL,
  temp_id      bigint NOT NULL,
  first_seen    numeric(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_on     timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  expire_on_gmt  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ip_from        inet NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0'::inet,
  "type"         smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  growth         numeric(8,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  seen          boolean DEFAULT false,

  CONSTRAINT tips_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX tips_idx_users_id01
  ON public.tips
  (users_id);
```

I really don't understand why this poor performance, it seems that the server do a JOIN under the hood...
Any help is appreciate.

Thanks
Perez

EDIT - 2018.10.9
Despite the accepted answer, who solve immediately the problem, thanks to a deeper investigation of Pavel Stehule (see posts below), the real problem was a incorrect statistics of the ***follows*** table. VACUUM ANALYZE solve the problem, both queryes run fast now.

Comment: And the query plan for the 4.7ms query is...

Comment: @CaiusJard Question updated with the plan

Comment: Must be that `follows` is a view. Can you share its definition?

Comment: Can you you post the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`? It might bee that your `tips_idx_users_id01` is bloated which would be visible when seeing how many buffers needed to be retrieved

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  question updated with table definition and explain with buffers

Comment: 2359507 buffers for  2353909 seems way too much for an index that contains one or two integers. What is the exact definition of the index `tips_idx_users_id01` and the table `tips`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name question updated with definitions and server specs

Comment: @user3262353 - looks like optimizer error

Comment: Did you try a `vacuum analyze` on the tables in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend write the query as:

```
select t.id
from tips t
where exists (select 1
              from follows f
              where f.users_id_from = 1 and f.users_id_to = t.users_id
             );
```

And creating an index on `follow(users_id_to, users_id_from)` -- the two columns in that order.

As to why Postgres chooses that execution plan.  Postgres thinks it is the best one.  Sometimes optimizers make mistakes.  Perhaps statistics are not up-to-date on the table.

EDIT:

Hmmm.  I wonder if either of these versions would encourage Postgres to use the index on `tips(id)`:

```
with f as (
      select users_id_to
      from follows
      where users_id_from = 1
     )
select t.id
from tips t
where t.users_id in (select f.users_id_to from f);
```

This gives Postgres the option (encourages?) of materializing the subquery and then using the index.

The second would be a simple `join`:

```
select t.id
from tips t join
     follows f
     on f.users_id_to = t.id
where f.users_id_from = 1
```

Comment: Execution time: 10272.144 ms

Comment: @user3262353 . . . With the index?

Comment: Sure. I also tried to delete all other indexes with same results

Comment: Bingo! the CTE version "with f as (..." solve the problem: 0.22 sec But it is avery strange behaviour on a so simple situation...

Comment: @user3262353 . . . I would agree.  SQL optimizers are quite tricky.  You can join the chorus that wants Postgres to support query hints:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/OptimizerHintsDiscussion.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying test case, and I got strongly different plan:

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from foo where a in (select a from boo where b = 22);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nested Loop  (cost=16.19..7066.65 rows=2101 width=8) (actual time=0.444..11.667 rows=2713 loops=1)                           |
|   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9.43..9.50 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.094..0.111 rows=9 loops=1)                              |
|         Group Key: boo.a                                                                                                     |
|         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on boo  (cost=4.33..9.42 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.048..0.071 rows=9 loops=1)              |
|               Recheck Cond: (b = 22)                                                                                         |
|               Heap Blocks: exact=5                                                                                           |
|               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on boo_b_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=9 loops=1) |
|                     Index Cond: (b = 22)                                                                                     |
|   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=6.75..1005.16 rows=300 width=8) (actual time=0.256..1.143 rows=301 loops=9)             |
|         Recheck Cond: (a = boo.a)                                                                                            |
|         Heap Blocks: exact=2678                                                                                              |
|         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_a_idx  (cost=0.00..6.68 rows=300 width=0) (actual time=0.145..0.145 rows=301 loops=9)   |
|               Index Cond: (a = boo.a)                                                                                        |
| Planning time: 0.971 ms                                                                                                      |
| Execution time: 12.105 ms                                          ဠ                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(15 rows)
```

And although I penalize some methods I got significantly better plans -

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from foo where a in (select a from boo where b = 22);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nested Loop  (cost=18.03..7894.11 rows=2101 width=8) (actual time=0.433..9.809 rows=2713 loops=1)                          |
|   ->  Unique  (cost=17.60..17.63 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.384..0.407 rows=9 loops=1)                                 |
|         ->  Sort  (cost=17.60..17.62 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.383..0.388 rows=9 loops=1)                             |
|               Sort Key: boo.a                                                                                              |
|               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                         |
|               ->  Seq Scan on boo  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.047..0.358 rows=9 loops=1)             |
|                     Filter: (b = 22)                                                                                       |
|                     Rows Removed by Filter: 991                                                                            |
|   ->  Index Scan using foo_a_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..1122.21 rows=300 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.874 rows=301 loops=9) |
|         Index Cond: (a = boo.a)                                                                                            |
| Planning time: 0.957 ms                                                                                                    |
| Execution time: 10.399 ms                                                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(12 rows)
```

Tested on PostgreSQL 10.5

After some gaming I got:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Gather  (cost=1018.03..117733.71 rows=2101 width=8) (actual time=113.420..914.035 rows=2713 loops=1)                                                 |
|   Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                 |
|   Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                |
|   ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=18.03..116523.61 rows=875 width=8) (actual time=150.675..904.224 rows=904 loops=3)                                      |
|         Merge Cond: (foo.a = boo.a)                                                                                                                  |
|         ->  Parallel Index Scan using foo_a_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..113510.99 rows=1250000 width=8) (actual time=0.136..800.463 rows=919564 loops=3) |
|         ->  Sort  (cost=17.60..17.62 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.347..0.357 rows=9 loops=3)                                                       |
|               Sort Key: boo.a                                                                                                                        |
|               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                   |
|               ->  Seq Scan on boo  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.059..0.286 rows=9 loops=3)                                       |
|                     Filter: (b = 22)                                                                                                                 |
|                     Rows Removed by Filter: 991                                                                                                      |
| Planning time: 0.903 ms                                                                                                                              |
| Execution time: 914.283 ms                                                                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(14 rows)
```

It is strange so you have not active paralelism (probably due low cost, but the estimation looks well). And although I was pretty ugly on optimizer, I got the query max 1sec long.

Can you run VACUUM FULL on complete database? Is not some other activity on your IO?

Follow up - the issue was related to missing or obsolete statistic on follows table. It has dramatics effect, because merge join has some optimization based on comparing max values from both tables. When one value is significantly lower, than it expects less reading and early ending. This is reason of strange low cost of merge join.

Comment: Reindexed, no difference. random_page_cost was not changed, it is a plain new installation.

Comment: After add 1 CPU core (2 total now) and a VACUUM FULL, the time decrease from 10.5 sec to 7.70 sec. This is a plain Digital Ocean droplet, no other services, and the total database size on disk is 500Mb plus 240Mb for indexes.

Comment: Please, try to reduce effective_cache to 300MB. Default is 4GB and it can be out of reality for 2GB notebook.

Comment: @user3262353 .- I try to reproduce your execution plan and all defaults works perfectly - are you sure so you have PostgreSQL 10? What is result of `select version()`

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: @user3262353 - it looks well, I don't understand why PostgreSQL has different behave on your comp. Can me send your data (or prepare reproducer)? Please, test decreasing effective cache size, if it helps?

Comment: effective_cache_size was 4GB, reduced to 1GB the time increase from 7.70sec to 9.50 sec. What do you mean for "prepare reproducer"?

Comment: @user3262353 - for 2GB notebook 1GB can be still too much. The safe value should to change your execution plan. Reproducer - I need random data, that has same features like your real data. If I have a reproducer test case, than I can simulate this issue on my notebook. Unfortunately I am not able to do it now.

Comment: How can I send you detailed info?

Comment: @user3262353 - my email is pavel.stehule@gmail.com